# How to retrieve foreign key column data using primary key column of a table

Tags: sql, oracle, foreign-keys

Let's say I have a table `store` with columns `store_id` (PK) and `store_address`, and I have another table `store_manager` with columns `manager_id` (Pk), `pwd`, `store_id` (fk to `store.store_id`).

I want to get `store_id` from `store_manager` using `manager_id` and `pwd`

Comment: But you already have store id in your store_manager table. Yes it's a foreign key, but you only need to use it as one to get data from the store table, which the scenario you lay out doesn't require.

Comment: Suppose when manager tries to check his store id by using his user Id n pwd is a scenario.... Then how to get store_id

Answer (score 1):

If you are just looking for the store_id from the table store_manager. you need a simple select statement

```
SELECT store_id from store_manager where manager_id = YOUR_VALUE;
```

If you are looking to get the data related to store using the foreign key use the joins.

```
SELECT STORE.store_address, store_manager.store_id from store_manager, store
where store_manager.manager_id = YOUR_VALUE
AND store_manager.store_id = store.store_id;
```

Let me know if you are looking for more details.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I want to get store_id details using user_id and pwd of store_manager table

Comment: So 1st query will do your work done just Add 1 more and condition in the where clause for pwd. If you are getting any errors/issues doing so?

Comment: I did same but it's not selecting any rows

Comment: Please share your query and data you are expecting to return.

Comment: I need to get store_id(it is a foreign key to Store_manager table and Primary key of Store table) from Store_manager table using user_id(Primary key of store_manager) and pwd of store_manager table. Thank for your responses